# either easier or easy

Tags: usage

Is the following sentence incorrect?

> If it sounds familiar, it's time to make some subtle changes to your daily life to make it ***easy*** to lose some extra weight and keep it off for good.

I think it is correct, but my answer key says it should be **easier** instead of **easy**.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence as you have written is *grammatically* correct. There is no issue with the tenses, etc.

It's a question of nuance. As the sentence describes the process of dieting, there is implied knowledge that it is not 'easy' to lose weight. Therefore, the subtle changes mentioned would make the process *easier*, but not an easy process that completes quickly.

Comment: But if I use easy instead of easier would that be ungrammatical?